# Xero API - how to retrieve online Quote URL or Quote PDF

Tags: xero-api

Does anyone know of a way to retrieve a quote URL or Quote in PDF format using the Xero API?  I know this is possible with Invoices but for some reason the API is lacking on the Quote side.

If not possible, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the API says "Individual quotes (e.g. Quotes/97c2dc5-cc47-4afd-8ec8-74990b8761e9) can also be returned as PDF's see our HTTP GET documentation" - that link then says "Individual Invoices, Individual Quotes and Credit Notes can also be returned in PDF format by setting the “Accept” value in the http header to “application/pdf”."

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/quotes#overview

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/requests-and-responses#http-get

Are you saying that doesn't work?

Comment: I managed to get part of it working as it now returns a PDF file as expected.  Only thing is the PDF file is blank :-/ https://codeshare.io/bvPW07

Comment: I can't say why that would be. I finally got around to testing this, and for an invoice it returns the PDF as expected. I don't have any quotes to test on. You might want to contact Xero API support and see if they can assist.